# Nodejs custom error class throws "TypeError: ValidationError is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Looking at some of the other questions on constructing classes, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a custom error class called ValidationError that lives in the file validationError.js:

```
class ValidationError extends Error {
constructor(message, errors) {
    super(message);
    this.errors = errors;
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    if (typeof Error.captureStackTrace === 'function') {
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    } else {
        this.stack = (new Error(message)).stack;
    }
}
}

module.exports = ValidationError;
```

I require this class in another file like so:

```
const { ValidationError } = require('./validationError');
```

And call it like this, which is the line that throws the error:

```
const validationError = new ValidationError('JSON failed validation.', result.errors);
```

The thrown error is, "TypeError: ValidationError is not a constructor".

I am on Node 10.6.4.

So what am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you using native ES6 or is there a transpilation step?

Comment: I'd recommend `Error.captureStackTrace(this, new.target);` (though actually this *should* happen inside the `super` call already)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not exporting an object with a `.ValidationError` constructor, you're directly setting the class as the `module.exports`. So in your import it should be

```
const ValidationError = require('./validationError');
```

and not use destructuring syntax.